# Design Patterns in Database Applications with Java (Java EE / Java SE)

Tags: java, database, design-patterns, postgresql

I've been reading StackOverflow for quite a while now and I'm only now building the nerve to ask a question. I'm 20 years old and currently enrolled in college in IT here in my hometown (Cluj-Napoca, Romania). Enough for introductions :D.

Basically I have my little software firm that provides Book-keeping appz. They're (horrifyingly) written in Delphi and I want to start from scratch and write them in Java. I've had little experience with Java in the past but I want to learn and I've chosen Java because of the cheap and quality tools the platform offers.

Now could you please point me to the right direction as where could I find some complete documentation (books, web-sites, blogs etc) as where to get some info on properly building database applications including design patterns with DBs(my choice is PostgreSQL and have already ordered a book) and also Java. I know I won't be able to get it right the first time but at least get it close to right.

Thank you

Comment: And welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: welcome at so :-)

There are a lot of good and free resources covering Java as a language ( e.g. [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java) ), and the reference documentation by Sun is also quite comprehensive. Once you have understood the basics of the language, I think its time to dive into the depths of database applications, and patterns. How?

First of all, you should try to build some simple database schemes, "playground"-scenarios are helpful from what I can tell. Imagine e.g. a library and try to model that. It doesn't take long yet you will learn a lot.

For patterns, I generally think of them as a guide, like the MVC pattern which you will likely incorporate. Don't force yourself to use them all in the first place, try to understand one at a time and refactor your code to have some pattern represented there rather than writing to a pattern in the first place.

So, good luck! ( and of course, once you're stuck, just ask! )

Comment: Thanks a lot, also for the quickness of the answer. I have a few books ob the language itself which I read but that's just the tip of the iceberg. Will look more into MVC and what's it all about. Again thank you

Answer (score 2):

[Head First Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596009208) is a great place to start.

[image: Head First Java]

Comment: Thank you Chris, will try to get my hands on this book also

Comment: I think I'm also going to get Head First Design Patterns. Is it good?

Comment: Yes, it's excellent!  However, I would recommend waiting until you have completed a few projects first.  You will get more out of the book if you have some experience and cases to relate it to.  I actually think Design Patterns may lead you down the wrong path if you don't have sufficient experience to guide you (i.e. you may get "pattern fever").  So, spend at least a year of two doing development and then go pick up a copy of design patterns.

Comment: But... aren't patterns like MVC useful to start with? I may be new to Java but not really new to programming. And I would like to build the appz in Java properly and following good patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Martin Fowler's "Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture" is quite popular.

http://martinfowler.com/books.html